# WPF binding in ItemTemplate works but produces error messages

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, itemtemplate, itemssource

I am using `Mahapps.Metro.Controls.DropDownButton` in a `UserControl` in my project, which I populate using data binding. In order to know which item gets selected, I apply an item template in which I specify the item click handler. The relevant XAML is

```
<Controls:DropDownButton
    x:Name="selector"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Content=" "
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Catalogues}"
>
   <Controls:DropDownButton.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" MouseDown="HandleDropDownItemMouseDown" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </Controls:DropDownButton.ItemTemplate>
</Controls:DropDownButton>
```

The `DataContext` is a custom view model set in the constructor in the code-behind for the user control:

```
public CatalogueEditor()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        this.viewModel = new CatalogueEditorViewModel();
        this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
}
```

The `Catalogues` property in the view model is a custom `KeyedCollection<string, Catalogue>` that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. This contains elements that are similar custom `KeyedCollection` objects implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`, but with item type `Question`, which is no longer a collection. `Catalogue` objects have a read-only property `Id`, to which I bind the `TextBlock` in the item template.

The binding seems to work all right and the `DropDownButton` gets populated with the `Id` labels of the `Catalogue` objects in the `Catalogues` collection, yet I get an output informing me of a binding error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Id' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-842352768)'. BindingExpression:Path=Id; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-842352768); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

This tells me that at some point the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock` in the item template is perceived as a `String`, though I intend it to be a `Catalogue` as an item in the collection bound to the `ItemsSource`. It is not only the correct operation that corroborates this notion but also my `HandleDropDownItemMouseDown` event handler:

```
void HandleDropDownItemMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && selector.IsExpanded) {
            Catalogue catalogue = ((TextBlock)e.Source).DataContext as Catalogue;

            if (catalogue != null) {
                viewModel.Select(catalogue);
            }
        }
}
```

Placing a breakpoint here I can see that the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock` is indeed a `Catalogue` and the code works as intended.

Why does this apparent error message occur? Shall I worry about it, does it signify that I made some insidious mistake in my code, or shall I be content that the code works? My apologies if this is an irrelevant or stupid question, but I am just learning WPF and I find it quite challenging, so I try to understand what happens around me even if my code happens to work. Your insights are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line is `Content=" "`. You are setting content of a control to `" "` string, to which control tries to apply your template. As `string` class has no `Id` property, it results in a binding error.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I shouldn't have figured it on my own, but of course it was.